# Unable to bind DataTemplateColumn element to another DataTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I am trying to  set an element in each DataGrid row by setting another element in the same row.
If `IsChecked` of the `ToggleButton` is True, image in the `ContentControl` will become visible.

I have cannibalised this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649874/change-visibility-of-grid-on-button-click-in-xaml) to try to get this to work. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650891/wpf-binding-an-element-in-a-datagridtemplatecolumn-to-an-element-in-another-dat) example seems similiar too and I hope I am not duplicating anything.

This is the code snippet from my implementation of the DataGrid:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid Margin="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
            <DataGrid 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=. , Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              Height="Auto" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"               
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              x:Name="Filter_grid"  
              Grid.Row="1">
                <DataGrid.Columns >
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="CAN ID"  Binding="{Binding Information.CAN_ID}" Width="50" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Messagen Name" Binding="{Binding Information.CAN_ID_description}" Width="300" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Information.Status}" Width="50" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header = "Filter ON" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Information.Tick}">
                                    <ContentControl.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType = "ContentControl" >
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>                                                   
                                                <DataTrigger  Binding = "{Binding  Path=IsChecked, ElementName=Filter_on}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property = "Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ContentControl.Style>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="F_column" Header ="Select">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ToggleButton  x:Name="Filter_on" Content="Switch" />                                                                   
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>             
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I am unable to get the ElementName to find the ToggleBox and get `Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Filter_on'`.

I have tried doing similiar with

`<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridTemplateColumn}}, Path=F_column.Filter_on}" Value="True">`, or using `x:Reference` which throws me an exception I can't decipher.

Comment: Why would you assume that one of the columns is the ancestor, in the visual tree, of another? Anyway, you should bind both to the same property of the row viewmodel. There's one instance of that template for each row in the grid. How would it decide which one to bind to? For that reason, an element name within a template is meaningful only within the template. Your first example has no datatemplate; the second binds to a property of the row viewmodel.

Comment: Remember, a DataGridColumn isn't a *thing* in the UI; it tells the DataGrid how to generate the cells in each row.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: you should never do this. XAML is very flexible and allows you to do some terribly clever things, but just because you can doesn't mean you should. The correct solution in this case is to create a view model for each row element with a boolean property that both the button and your data trigger can bind to. Apart from being more flexible it's also much easier to test, debug and log etc.

That said, what you are asking is technically possible. DataGrids are actually quite complex due to various optimizations they employ etc, so you still need to use an intermediate property, but since you don't want to use a view model you'll have to use the `Tag` property in the button's DataGridCell instead (which can be used for arbitrary user data):

1. Bind the button's `IsChecked` property to do a one-way-to-source binding to it's parent DataGridCell's `Tag` property.
2. Bind the DataTrigger to find the parent `DataGridCellsPanel`, and then bind directly to the appropriate child's `Tag` property i.e. `Children[1].Tag`.

Put it together and you get this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header = "Filter ON" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl>
                        <ContentControl.Style>
                            <Style TargetType = "ContentControl" >
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger  Binding = "{Binding Path=Children[1].Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCellsPanel}}}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property = "Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ContentControl.Style>
                        <TextBlock Text="Content goes here" />
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>


        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="F_column" Header ="Select">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="Filter_on" Content="Switch" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

But seriously...just use a view model.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your detailed answer. I think I do use ViewModel, each of those rows has a model and they are assigned in the background code. I wanted to see how to set those from within XAMl only, I struggle a bit with assigment for relative paths. I have updated code in my question, I can not use the first line of your code as I am binding to a different property to get the rows.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you, which line are you referring to in particular? I can't see anything different in your updated code other than the fact that you'd have to bind to `Children[4].Tag` instead of `Children[1].Tag`. Both of the `Tag` bindings are using RelativeSource to an ancestor, so their respective data context bindings shouldn't interfere.